# Is there a way to create a global listener to receive message from a websocket?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, websocket, ionic-framework

I'm working a real time chat with AngularJS in Ionic. I have two views: chat, where I show all the conversations, and chat-detail to show the detail of one specific conversation. I'm using websockets, and I need a global listener to save all messages that I receive from the server maybe in a object or LocalStorage.

Is there a way to manage that messages anywhere in the project with angular?

UPDATE: I am using java as backend. I do not use nodejs to implement that funcionability.